# Помогите, пожалуйста, в питоне сделать цикл по времени, что бы все повторялось с периодом 1 минута

Tags: python, функции, циклы

```
from ast import While
import hashlib
import json
import requests
import time

from time import sleep
from setuptools import Command
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

app_id = "f4fc0a58-35ce-428e-aвыа"
secret = "cfnmFIOepUiываыва"
начиная отсюда, все повторялось с переодичностью 1 минута все что ниже в течение 3 часов
x=2
for nonce in range(x):
    nonce =str(time.time())
    params_string = json.dumps(
        {"app_id": app_id, "nonce": nonce},
        separators=(',', ':')
    )
    time.sleep(0.0000001)
    sign_get = hashlib.md5((params_string + secret).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
    token=requests.get(f'url?app_id={app_id}&nonce={nonce}&sign={sign_get}')
    # print(token.text)  
    token = json.loads(token.text)
    print('Наш токен', token['token'])


    print('Наш случайный нонс', nonce)

    zapros = dict()
    zapros['app_id'] = app_id
    zapros['command'] ={функция
}
    zapros['nonce'] = nonce
    zapros['token'] = token['token']
    zapros['type'] = 'printCheck'
    k = json.dumps(zapros , ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ':'))
    print(k)  
    sign_post = hashlib.md5((k + secret).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
    print('Подпись для пост запроса ', sign_post)
 headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
    headers["sign"] = sign_post
    headers["Authorization"] = token['token']
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

    data = k.encode('utf8')


    resp = requests.post("url/Command", headers=headers, data=data)

    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.text)
```

Comment: ну добавь паузу длиной в минуту

Comment: Спасибо, так работает, но хотелось как то отдельный циклом итерации прописывать

Comment: В чем конкретно затруднения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо строки с `print` вставляете свой код, который должен повторяться 3 часа:

```
import time

time_now = time.time()
time_end = time_now + 10800  # 10800 секунд = 3 часа
while time_now < time_end:
    print('вместо этой строки вставляете код')
    time.sleep(60)
    time_now = time.time()
```

Comment: не совсем так. спать нужно (60 - время выполнения кода)